# trying to send TCP packet and recieve it back and count time in client+server app

Tags: c, tcp, udp, packet

I have app to do that send 30k byte packet in to server, receive it back (100 attempts) and counts average time of that.

It has to have 2 dif type of sockets: UDP and TCP. With UDP its working fine, but with TCP it's looping in a last while (client-side). I assume that TCP is working differently than UDP, and the packed send isn't the same that i recieve.

Please look at my code:

client (has to be run second)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1000
#define ATTEMPTS 10

char buf[BUFFER_SIZE];

/*
argv[1] - nazwa hosta
argv[2] - numer portu UDP
argv[3] - numer portu TCP
*/

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct sockaddr_in endpoint;
    int sdsocket, sdsocket2, addrlen, i, received, j=0, r_sendto, r_recvfrom;
    struct hostent *he;
    struct timeval time_b, time_e;

    if (argc<4) {
        printf("podaj nazwe hosta i numery portu jako parametry (1 UDP, 2 TCP)\n");
        return 1;
    }

    he = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (he == NULL) {
        printf("Nieznany host (unknown kost): %s\n",argv[1]);
        return 0;
    }

    memset(&endpoint, 0, sizeof(endpoint));

    endpoint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    endpoint.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));
    endpoint.sin_addr = *(struct in_addr*) he->h_addr;
    addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    ////////////// UDP //////////////////
    gettimeofday(&time_b, NULL);
    if ((sdsocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0){
        perror("socket UDP() nie powiodl sie");
        return 1;
    }

    while(ATTEMPTS>j){
        r_sendto = sendto(sdsocket,
                            buf,
                            BUFFER_SIZE,
                            0,
                            (struct sockaddr*) &endpoint,
                            addrlen);
        if (r_sendto == -1) {
            perror("sendto() nie powiodl sie (failed)\n");
            //close(sdsocket); //?
            return 1;
        }
        
        r_recvfrom = recvfrom(sdsocket,
                            buf,
                            BUFFER_SIZE,
                            0,
                            (struct sockaddr*) &endpoint,
                            &addrlen);
        if (r_recvfrom == -1){
            perror("recvfrom() nie powidl sie (failed)\n");
            break;
        }
        j++; 
    }
    close(sdsocket);
    gettimeofday(&time_e, NULL);


    printf("Czas dla 30k-bajtowych bloków (UDP): %.6f s\n",
        (((double) (time_e.tv_sec - time_b.tv_sec) * 1000000) +
        ((double) (time_e.tv_usec - time_b.tv_usec)))
        / (1000000.0 * ATTEMPTS));

    ////////////// TCP //////////////////

    sleep(2);

    endpoint.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[3]));

    if ((sdsocket2 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("socket TCP() nie powiodl sie (failed)\n");
        return 1;
    }
 
    gettimeofday(&time_b, NULL);
    
    if (connect(sdsocket2,(struct sockaddr*) &endpoint, addrlen) < 0) {
        perror("connect() nie powiodl sie");
        return 0;
    }

    for (i=0; i<ATTEMPTS; i++) {
        send(sdsocket2, buf, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
        received = 0;

        while (received < BUFFER_SIZE)
        {
            printf("test %d\n", i);

            int ret = recv(sdsocket2,
                            buf+received,
                            BUFFER_SIZE-received,
                            0);
            
            if (ret <=0){
                if (ret = 0){
                    printf("ret=0 - serwer zamknal\n");
                }
                else{
                    fprintf(stderr, "recv error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                }
             break;
            }
           received += ret; 
        }
       
    }
    close(sdsocket2);
    gettimeofday(&time_e, NULL);

    printf("Czas dla 30k-bajtowych bloków (TCP): %.6f s\n",
        (((double) (time_e.tv_sec - time_b.tv_sec) * 1000000) +
        ((double) (time_e.tv_usec - time_b.tv_usec)))
        / (1000000.0 * ATTEMPTS));
    return 0;
}
```

server (has to be run first):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1000
#define ATTEMPTS 10

char buf[BUFFER_SIZE];

/*
argv[1] - numer portu dla UDP
argv[2] - numer portu dla TCP
*/
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct sockaddr_in myaddr, client_addr;
    int sdsocketUDP, sdsocketTCP; //sdsocket dla UDP/TCP
    int addrlen, received, i, sdconnection;
    socklen_t client_addrlen;

    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("podaj numer portu jako parametry (1 UDP, 2 TCP)\n");
        return 1;
    }
    sdsocketUDP = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    myaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    myaddr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));
    myaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if (bind(sdsocketUDP, (struct sockaddr*) &myaddr, addrlen) < 0) {
        perror("bind() nie powiodl sie (failed)\n");
        return 1;
    }

    client_addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in); //???
    printf("test1\n");
    ////////////// UDP //////////////////
    memset(buf, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
    for (i = 0; i < ATTEMPTS; i++) {
        received = recvfrom(sdsocketUDP,
                            buf,
                            BUFFER_SIZE,
                            0,
                            (struct sockaddr*) &client_addr,
                            &client_addrlen);

        if (received == -1) {
            perror("recvfrom() nie powiodl sie");
           // close(sdsocketUDP); //?
            return 1;
        }

        sendto(sdsocketUDP,
               buf,
               BUFFER_SIZE,
               0,
               (struct sockaddr*) &client_addr,
               client_addrlen);
    }
    close(sdsocketUDP);
    ////////////// TCP //////////////////
    
    //myaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    myaddr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));
    //myaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    sdsocketTCP = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    // zmienione addrlen na sizeof(myaddr)
    if (bind(sdsocketTCP, (struct sockaddr*) &myaddr, addrlen) < 0) {
    perror("bind() nie powiodl sie (failed)\n");
    return 1;
    }

    client_addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
  
    if (sdsocketTCP < 0) {
        perror("socket TCP() nie powiodl sie (failed)\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (listen(sdsocketTCP, 10) < 0) {
        perror("listen() nie powiodl sie (failed)\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Czekam na polaczenie (I am waiting for connection)...\n");

    while ((sdconnection =
                accept(sdsocketTCP,
                       (struct sockaddr*) &client_addr,
                       &client_addrlen)) >= 0)
    {

        memset(buf, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
        received = 0;
        while (received < BUFFER_SIZE) {
            received += recv(sdconnection,
                             buf + received,
                             BUFFER_SIZE - received,
                             0);
               
                                   
        }
        send(sdconnection, buf, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
        close(sdconnection);   
    }
    close(sdsocketTCP);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried changing number of bytes send in case of blocks being partitioned, adding sleep in client in case server isn't responding/answering on time, but didn't work.

Chat GPT can't tell the answer or hint. I think issue is with it how TCP works.

Cheers.

Comment: You don't check how much bytes were actually `send` but blindly assume that all were send. This assumption is wrong. With UDP this is all or nothing, with TCP this can also be part of the given buffer. You also don't check the return value if `recv` in the server but blindly assume that it will always be greater than 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your TCP server seems to close the accepted TCP connection after receiving BUFFER_SIZE bytes:

```
    while ((sdconnection =
            accept(sdsocketTCP,
                   (struct sockaddr*) &client_addr,
                   &client_addrlen)) >= 0)
    {
        ...
        while (received < BUFFER_SIZE) {
            ...
        }
        ....
        close(sdconnection);   
    }
```

Because the TCP client try to use the same TCP connection for ATTEMPTS  * BUFFER_SIZE  bytes, the server closes the connection too early, and starts waiting next connection.

Quick and dirty(?) fix for the server would be:

Echo all data from the client until the TCP connection is closed (recv() returns 0 or -1). For example something like this:

```
    while ((sdconnection =
            accept(sdsocketTCP,
                   (struct sockaddr*) &client_addr,
                   &client_addrlen)) >= 0)
    {
        while (1)
            int len = recv(sdconnection, buf, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);                
            if (len <= 0)
                 break;
            send(sdconnection, buf, len, 0);
        };
        close(sdconnection);   
    }
```

Comment: Thank You. You fixed main problem (previously while was set to recieve only BUFFER_SIZE of bytes and then close connection). Infinity loop works better in this case and will be closed only if connection is closed client-side.